# Magento2: Minicart doesn't show items in the dropdown popup

Tags: magento2, mini-cart

I'm using Magento version 2.1.1 and facing issue that minicart is not showing added items in the cart.

In firebug, its showing this error message: "TypeError: this.itemRenderer is undefined"

Any help would be appreciated.